# How does Android restart persistent services

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a service for managing persistent Android services.  I would like to provide the capability to configure the rate at which the managed services get restarted after failing (number of restarts within a given time).  I know that Android has a service manager that will restart services automatically. I have not found a way to configure the restart rate for the native service manager, so my plan was to perform any additional restarts or disable the service as needed.  So that leaves me with two questions. How does Android restart persistent services? I assume it is using the Activity Manager class, but I do not know what intent get sent or where the restart intent for a service is defined. Is there an easy way to track the restarts so that I can take over where Android leaves off?

Example functionality I would like to provide: 
1. Service A registers to be managed by my service manager. 
2. Service A sets the configurable restart rate to 100 restarts within a 5 minute window. 
3. Service A crashes 5 times in 5 seconds and is restarted each time by the OS.
4. Service A crashes again. This time it is deemed by the OS to have reached an excessive amount of restarts and is not restarted.
5. My service manager restarts the service up to the 95 remaining restarts as needed.
6. If the 100 restart limit is reached within the configured 5 minute interval, then disable the service until the window of time has passed.
7. Repeat.

Comment: "I am trying to create a service for managing persistent Android services" -- I assume that this is part of a broader project to create a custom Android firmware build, with revisions to the OS itself. "I have not found a way to configure the restart rate for the native service manager" -- that would be part of your modifications to the OS itself. "I assume it is using the Activity Manager class" -- `ActivityManager` in the Android SDK doesn't do much of anything. It is an API for talking to a core OS process.

Comment: You are correct in assuming that this is a small part of a very broad project, and that revisions to the OS itself are possible.  However I would very much like to avoid modifying the OS if there is another way. If the OS is doing all of the service management, is there a way to access or watch for restart intents being sent from the OS?